# electron remote is undefined with enableremotemodule = true

Tags: typescript, electron

I am trying to use dialog with `"electron": "^13.1.4"` , but got an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined.` , Even if I set `enableremotemodule = true`.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
......
......

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        contextIsolation: false,
        enableremotemodule: true,
        nodeIntegration: true,
    }
});
```

and this is the code call the electron remote and got undefined

```
import { OpenDialogOptions, remote } from 'electron';
.......
.......
openFile() {
    let options: OpenDialogOptions = {};
    console.log(remote); // log undefined
    remote.dialog.showOpenDialog(options).then((filePath) => {
        console.log(filePath);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `OpenDialogOptions` there is no item in electron documentation
try with

`const { dialog } = require('electron').remote`

and change the case in main.js as  `enableRemoteModule: true`

Please refer this [Dialog documentation by electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog)

Comment: OpenDialogOptions is the interface defined at electron.d.ts, and enableRemoteModule: true had been set in main.js as the above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using elect 14.0 or above `remote` is no longer part of core electron but you can include

```
const {dialog} = require('@electron/remote');
```

you should also initialize remote in the main process and allow your window to execute remote

In your main process do this

```
require("@electron/remote/main").initialize();
const mainRemote = require("@electron/remote/main");
mainRemote.enable(win.webContents);
```

In your renderer process

```
const remote = window.require("@electron/remote");
const { getCurrentWebContents, getCurrentWindow, dialog } = remote;

const webContents = getCurrentWebContents();
const currentWindow = getCurrentWindow();

//now show your dialog
   const response = dialog.showMessageBoxSync(currentWindow, {
        buttons: ["Yes", "No"],
        message: "Do you really want to save?",
        title: "Confirm order"
      });
```

Note: enableRemoteModule no longer works in electron version >= 14.0

[Reference](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#planned-breaking-api-changes-140)

Comment: Related question: Do you know why something like `import remote from '@electron/remote'` doesn't behave? I can't get that to play nicely with my `vue` components